# Corona: attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

I have a class that creates a space ship and I want it to include a function that makes the ship remove itself if it bumps into a specific wall.
However, running the code below, I get the following error:

```
...xenosShip.lua:16:
attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
[C]:?
...xenosShip.lua:16: in function ...xenosShip.lua:14> ?:in function <?:218
```

>

What am I missing?

```
local xenosShip = {}

-- XENOS SHIP COLLISION
local function xenosColl(event)
    if (event.phase == "began" and event.other.myName == "bottomWall") then
    self:removeSelf()
    end
end


-- XENOS SHIP
function xenosShip.new()

    local newXenosShip=display.newSprite( alShipSheet, alShipSeqData )
    newXenosShip:play()
    newXenosShip.x=300
    newXenosShip.y=70
    newXenosShip.myName = "newXenosShip"
    physics.addBody(newXenosShip,"dynamic", {density = 1.0, friction = 0.3, bounce = 1})
    newXenosShip:applyForce(50,2500,newXenosShip.x,newXenosShip.y)
    newXenosShip:addEventListener("collision", xenosColl)

end

return xenosShip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, the `self` is not a display object or it has no reference to a display object so there's an error in `object:removeSelf()`

```
local function xenosColl(event)
    if (event.phase == "began" and event.other.myName == "bottomWall") then
        event.target:removeSelf()
    end
end
```

If you want to use **self** you can do it like this. So the self is now referring to the `newXenosShip`.

```
function xenosShip.new()

    local newXenosShip=display.newSprite( alShipSheet, alShipSeqData )
    newXenosShip:play()
    newXenosShip.x=300
    newXenosShip.y=70
    newXenosShip.myName = "newXenosShip"
    physics.addBody(newXenosShip,"dynamic", {density = 1.0, friction = 0.3, bounce = 1})
    newXenosShip:applyForce(50,2500,newXenosShip.x,newXenosShip.y)
    newXenosShip.collision = function(self,event)
        if (event.phase == "began" and event.other.myName == "bottomWall") then
                self:removeSelf()
        end
    end

    newXenosShip:addEventListener("collision")
end
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! May I inquire as to why the newXenosShip seems to be the event target and not the self in this case? I've used the same construction earlier in the code, although not in a class and it worked fine there.

Comment: It depends on the class on how you referenced the display object to the class. I'm sorry I can't explain it very well, I'm still new in Corona and Lua.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same error message; for me, it was a simple syntactic error, instead of

```
 playerInstance:resetTargetPosition()
```

I had used

```
 playerInstance.resetTargetPosition()
```

(note the `.` instead of the `:`)